# UWP Menu Bar not displaying

Tags: xaml, uwp

I followed the instructions from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/menus#create-a-menu-bar) article from official `UWP` team using `VS2017` on my `Windows 10 version 1809`. But the following `XAML` is not showing menu bar. I've tested it on top of the app window and then even in the middle of the window but to no avail. I've also installed `Windows UI Library` following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/getting-started) article. What could be a reason and how to resolve the issue?

```
<Page
    x:Class="Junk_UWP.MainPage"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Junk_UWP"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <MenuBar Margin="0,338,0,622" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <MenuBarItem Title="File">
                <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="New">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Plain Text Document"/>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Rich Text Document"/>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Other Formats..."/>
                </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Open..."/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Save"/>
                <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Exit"/>
            </MenuBarItem>

            <MenuBarItem Title="Edit">
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Undo"/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Cut"/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Copy"/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Paste"/>
            </MenuBarItem>

            <MenuBarItem Title="Help">
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="About"/>
            </MenuBarItem>
        </MenuBar>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="750,466,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Snapshot of Design Page of above Xaml**:

[image]

Comment: So when you click on 'File', you can't see New, Open or Save?

Comment: Try setting your minimum version to 17763.

Comment: @GailFoad It does not show menu bar at all. Also, per the requirements described in the first link provided above, I am already using both min and max versions as `17763`.

Comment: Does it work if you try running the project from the article: https://github.com/Microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason seems to be your huge vertical margins for the MenuBar. You need quite a big window and screen to display those margins. Also it doesn't make sense to use `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`, though I am not sure if it can break something.

Comment: You're right - if I use the same code as nam but change the menu bar to  Margin="0,250,0,250", the menu bar is displayed.